# Passing additional parameters to execute function in Sencha Test

Tags: extjs, sencha-test, sencha-test-2.1

Is there a way to pass additional parameters to an execute function in Sencha Test? In a web driver scenario a closure is not an option. http://docs.sencha.com/sencha_test/2.1.1/api/ST.html#method-execute

Take for example:

```
selectColumn: function () {

        this.columnsComboBox().execute(function (cmp) { // I would like to pass another param here 
            return cmp.getStore().findRecord('name', 'Oranges').get('id');
        })
            .and(function () {
                combo.setValue(this.future.data.executeResult);
            });
    }
```

It would be nice to be able to pass `Oranges` as a param instead of having it hardcoded so this function could be reused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, this is not currently possible. However, it's a really good idea I think, so I've created a feature request for this. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, this feature will be available in the next release of Sencha Test.